# Getting error when passing more than 1000 values in Django IN filter

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I have list which contains more than 1000 entires. I have to check out of those 1000 entries how man exist in my table so I am using Django IN filter but it is giving me error

> Error: ('07002', u'[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

and when I reduce the list of values to around 400 it works.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to approach this. Thank You

Comment: Put the values in a (temporary) table, and join.

Comment: Please add your query set and database name to your question.

Comment: @jarlh very good suggestion. how can I use Temporary table in django orm and how can I execute this could you write that solution in the Answers ?

Comment: Sorry, my Django experience is even less.